# passing dynamic values in callback method

Tags: javascript, node.js

is there a way to pass dynamic values to callback function in js or jquery or nodejs.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  filename = 'file'+i+'.html';
  request(url, function(error, response, body) {
   test(error, response, body, filename);
  });
}

  function test(error, response, body, filename) {
   console.log('file name ' + filename);
   if(response.statusCode == 200){
    console.log('done');
   }
```

I refered this so article for passing values to callback function.

link: [JavaScript: Passing parameters to a callback function

**the output always seems to be 9**

How can i pass values dynamically? The callback function always refers the last value of filename.

Comment: its because your "request" call is asynchronous. use callback logic to overcome this problem.

Comment: @anand4tech how to acheive that.. can you give some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you changes the value of the same variable `filename` on each iteration.

So, you should somehow bind the value of `filename` to the context of `request` callback.

For example, you may call `request` inside of the anonimous function:

```
function test (error, response, body, filename) {
  console.log('file name ' + filename);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) console.log('done');
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  (function (filename) {
    request(url, function(error, response, body) {
      test(error, response, body, filename);
    });
  })('file'+i+'.html')
}
```

Alternative solution is to make your `test` function a function factory:

```
function test (filename) {
  return function (error, response, body) {
    console.log('file name ' + filename);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) console.log('done');
  };
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  request(url, test('file'+i+'.html'));
}
```